# Get tableDefs from SqlExpression<T>

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I have a method that takes a parameter of `SqlExpression<T>`.  The method basically takes an OrmLite query and performs some queries on it generated from a string input.

I really need to be able to get all table types for the query from `SqlExpression<T>` so I can generate an expression.

In the debugger I can see main table and joined tables are in a protected property called `tableDefs` but I cannot see any public accessor.

I can get via reflection:

```cs
public static class SqlExpressionExtension
{
    public static List<Type> GeTableTypes<T>(this SqlExpression<T> query)
    {
        return ((List<ModelDefinition>)query.GetType().GetField("tableDefs", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(query))
            .Select(x => x.ModelType).ToList(); 
    }
}
```

But I think would be better using public accessor.

Is there a proper way to get all table types from a `SqlExpression<T>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just added a `GetAllTables()` API in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/52f4bf674a090a7046a961ca5568af959c67b2fd) which returns the primary and joined tables added in an `SqlExpression<T>`.

This is available in the latest ServiceStack **v5.11.1+** that's now [available on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget).